# how to clear crontab ubuntu cache memory

Tags: server, cron, ram

I started my server and configured the server without cPanel or direct admin.
And to run queues in Laravel, I need to run cron, so I wrote the desired command in cron and everything works fine.
Until I noticed that cron is consuming too much RAM, while the execution of this queue is very light and is done every **5** minutes.
Now my question is how can I free up the RAM, thanks
[memory usage in crontab - please check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLmE9.png)

in this example memory usage equal 1.7 Gig. now how to clear memory usage?

Comment: Your systemctl status output also shows that cron is running 192 tasks - is that what you expect? Are you perhaps starting jobs faster than they are able to complete?

Comment: No. Only I run a queue that may have several queues based on user activities.
But still it will not be 192!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the memory usage is not cleared by any method and only by **rebooting**. I hope it helps others